# Comment out a block a file using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to comment out a block of code in a file using sed or awk.

Ex. Input

```
this is source file;
line one code;
line two code;
line three code;
line four code;
line 5 code;
if something then
  line 6 code;
end if;
```

In this, I want to comment out from line two of code to end if.

I.e the output should be

```
this is source file;
line one code;
/*
line two code;
line three code;
line four code;
line 5 code;
if something then
  line 6 code;
end if;
*/
```

Tried, this

```
awk '"/line two code;/{e=0}/end if;/" {printf("%s%s%s\n", "/*", $0, "*/"); next} {print}'
```

But, it appends /* and */ between each line of code.

Comment: Learn to debug your `awk` code in steps. I don't think that `"/line two code;/{e=0}/end if;/" ` is doing what you think/need. Good solution below. Good luck to all.

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and read the first couple of pages then revisit your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to comment out from `line two code` to `end if`:

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '/line two code;/{print "/*"; p++} 1; p && /end if;/{print "*/"; p=0}' file

this is source file;
line one code;
/*
line two code;
line three code;
line four code;
line 5 code;
if something then
  line 6 code;
end if;
*/
```

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly for the given usecase. But, if I have two if statements, it adds end comment (*/) for the second end if also.

Comment: It works fine for the given scenario. But

For for ex : it does not work for this source

this is source file;
line one code;
line two code;
line three code;
line four code;
line 5 code;
if something then
  line 6 code;
end if;

if something_else then
  line 7 code;
end if;

Comment: ok try this `awk` command: `awk '/line two code;/{print "/*"; p++} 1; p && /end if;/{print "*/"; p=0}' file`

Comment: Perfect :). Works like a charm. Thank you @anubhava

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `sed` works pretty much the same way:

```
sed '/line two code;/s|$|\n/*|; /end if;/s|$|\n*/|' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Arunkumar Ramamoorthy, I think the following code may help:

```
awk '/line two code;/{print "/*"}{print $0}/end if;/{print "*/"}' input
```

At least, It works on my mac

```
➜  ShellBean cat input 
this is source file;
line one code;
line two code;
line three code;
line four code;
line 5 code;
if something then
  line 6 code;
end if;
➜  ShellBean awk '/line two code;/{print "/*"}{print $0}/end if;/{print "*/"}' input
this is source file;
line one code;
/*
line two code;
line three code;
line four code;
line 5 code;
if something then
  line 6 code;
end if;
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed $'/line two code/{:a;N;/end if/!ba;i/*\n;a*/\n}' file
```

This stuffs the lines between the two literals into the pattern space and then inserts and appends the required lines when printing them out.

N.B. the `$'...` is bashism that allows the one-liner to include newlines, however if you prefer multiple commands will work too:

```
sed -e '/line two code/{:a;N;/end if/!ba;i/*' -e 'a*/' -e '}' file
```