# Replace block of code surrounded by nested curly braces

Tags: regex, shell, nginx, awk, sed

I have this block of setting:

```
...
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replace whole server block with another block. Looking to use AWK or SED. 
Replaced with

```
...
    server {
        listen              80;
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    }
}
```

Regex pattern that I found working on selecting what I needed.
Using -m (Multiline) modifier. Tool used: Regex101.com

`server {(?:[^}]*}[^}])*` or `server {[\S\s]*(?=^\s{4}\}$)\s*}`

Comment: `awk` is much better suited to solving this sort of problem. Are you required  (for some crazy reason) to use `sed`? AND, you realize that it is advanced usage of `sed` to build up a multi-line hold space to then match a pattern against? Good luck.

Comment: That wasn't even on my radar, I was going off from one of the shell scripts I modified long time ago that was doing server configuration and used sed. Thank you. Will research in to it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38460982/620097 for some ideas. (flag variables). Unfortunately, you're asking to read in a whole separate file (right?), so you'll need something using `getline()`, but I don't have time to figure it out. Update your Q with your best attempt to solve in awk, (and an `awk` tag) and the awk brigade will be along to help out. Good luck.

Comment: And, as it seems, you're going to be doing this more than once, maybe you want to refactor your process into multiple blocks of cfg items that you "glue" together, i.e. `{echo "header stuff" ; cat userInfo.cfg appInfo.cfg serverInfo.cfg securityInfo.cfg .... ; echo "close it up" ; } > newCfgFile.cfg` where any of those cfg files could be variable values that are set in the script preceding the creation of the final file, based on tests, conditions, etc. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter - while awk is the right tool to use, the OP will not need to use getline. Dennis - [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input (and maybe even improve the input to be more interesting) and someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiasm, greatly appreciated! That is not what should happened. As it said only replace selected. The context of replaced message is trivial at this point, the difficult part was getting the selection right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MAY be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
braceCnt {
    if ( /{/ ) { braceCnt++ }
    if ( /}/ ) { braceCnt-- }
}
!braceCnt
/^[[:space:]]*server[[:space:]]*{/ {
    print newBlock
    braceCnt = 1
}

$ awk -v newBlock='        listen              80;
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;' -f tst.awk file
...
    server {
        listen              80;
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    }
}
```

or if you prefer relying on indentation/white space than counting braces, this would work too:

```
$ cat tst.awk
inBlock && /^ {4}}/ { inBlock=0 }
!inBlock
/^[[:space:]]*server[[:space:]]*{/ { print newBlock; inBlock=1 }
```

or if you just want the number of spaces before the closing brace to match the number before `server` rather than hard-coding it to `4`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
inBlock && ($0 ~ "^[[:space:]]{"indent"}}") { inBlock=0 }
!inBlock
/^[[:space:]]*server[[:space:]]*{/ {
    indent = index($0,"s") - 1
    print newBlock; inBlock=1
}
```

etc., etc.... It all depends on your requirements....

Answer (score 0):

select } that has four spaces before it and nothing behind on same line :

```
/^\s{4}\}$/m
```